# I forgot the password of my Bitcoin Core Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

In the past years, I had some Balance in Bitcoin Core wallet , but after 5 years, I forgot the transfer password and I only have the backup file (.dat).
Is there a solution that I can transfer the Balance with the help of my backup file and return its password?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the password is to prevent people who do not know the password from accessing the money.

Just pause and think about the above for a couple of minutes. Many highly skilled people put a lot of effort into ensuring you cannot do what you propose to do. Over many years, many other highly skilled people scrutinised the way it works to identify and eliminate weaknesses.

If there were a way around that, the password would be pointless. It isn't pointless.

If you remember that the password was very short, or you remember all but a few letters, you can try using a "brute force" tool that tries all possible variations. One that is often mentioned is btcrecover.

If you instead chose a sensible password,  it is almost certain no-one can ever find it in your lifetime.

Many people will contact you pretending to be recovery experts. Their intent is to gain your confidence and then trick you into giving them money.

Comment: Thank you for your help, what is the best   "brute force "tool to try this way in my Windows environment?

Comment: I don't know which is best but I would start with the one mentioned at the end of my fourth paragraph. I would make sure I was downloading it from the original source and I would try to run it on a machine that is not connected to the Internet.